# How can I log the IPs that processes on my computer are connecting to?

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet, process

My firewall is saying that my Windows 7 PC is connecting outbound to several suspicious IP addresses in a foreign country. I've run 5 different virus/malware scans, but I'm clean.

How can I determine what processes are connecting to those IPs? The connection isn't constant, so I would presume I'd need to log this kind of activity and review it later.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft SysInternals networking utility *TCPView* is probably useful for this purpose:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/tcpview

> TCPView is a Windows program that will show you detailed listings of
>   all TCP and UDP endpoints on your system, including the local and
>   remote addresses and state of TCP connections.

Answer (score 0):

*How can I determine what processes are connecting to those IPs?*

Resource Monitor is good for this, but only for monitoring connections in real-time.

*The connection isn't constant, so I would presume I'd need to log this kind of activity and review it later.*

You could make a .bat script like this:

```
:top
date /t
time /t
netstat /an
timeout 60
goto top
```

Then run it, outputting to some log file:

```
batfilename.bat >> networkConnections.log
```

The output might be difficult to parse, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Network Monitor](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/netmon/p/downloads/). It will capture all network activity and which processes are involved. From the GUI there is no option to log the capture to a file, just let it run in the background or use the command line tool.

Start `cmd.exe` as administrator and type:

```
nmcap.exe /network * /capture /file c:\netmon.chn:100MB
```

This command will capture everything to a file (max. size is 100 MB), when finished capturing hit `Ctrl-C` to stop the capturing process and open the file with the GUI Application to analyze its content. Note: when the max. file size is reached it will create a new log file with an incremental number.

**AS an alternative** use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/#download), a network protocol analyzer. It will capture all the network traffic to a log file. However it will not log the involved processes, as it only operates on the network layer, but it logs the ports involved.

Go to **Capture > Options > Output** and check **Capture to a permanent file** (optionally choose a location to save the cap file) and click **Start**. It will then start capturing all network activity to a file and present a live view on screen. At the top enter filters like:

```
ip.src == 1.2.3.4
```

If a process is listening on a static port, it can be identified using `netstat`.

Start `cmd.exe` as administrator and type:

```
netstat -anob
```

which gives a list of all currently listening processes and active network connections:

```
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:22             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2784
 [sshd.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       968
  RpcSs
  ...
```